# cumulative totals with shifted column

Tags: awk

Apologies in advance since I am sure this is an easy problem. Nevertheless, here goes.

```
cat blah.txt
aa+2
bb+4
cc+10
dd+31
```

I would like to process blah.txt to produce the folowing:

```
aa+0
bb+2
cc+6
dd+16
```

The notion here is that the first column might be a list of songs, and the second their start times.

My hunch was to do this using awk. I thought of two arrays with numeric indices storing $1 and the running total of $2. My idea was to shift the numeric index for the running totals by 1.

```
tail -r blah.txt | 
awk -F "+" '{ for(i=0;i<=NR;i++) arr[i+1]+=$2; farr[i]=$1 } END 
{ for(i=NR+1;i>1;i--) {if (i==NR) {print farr[NR] FS 0 } 
else { print farr[i] FS arr[i]}}}'
```

This isn't concise, and what's more doesn't work. I am befuddled by the failure of the array making above all.

Anyway, 'nuf said, could some kind person please put me out of my misery ?

Tom

Comment: If `-r` is to get `head` you can also do: `awk -F+ 'NR>10{exit}{pr...`

Answer (score 6):

Here you go:

```
$ awk -F+ '{sum+=$2;printf("%s+%d\n",$1,sum-$2);}' blah.txt
aa+0
bb+2
cc+6
dd+16
```

Edit1: here is a slightly simpler way, thanks to Sukminder

```
$ awk -F+ '{printf("%s+%d\n",$1,sum);sum+=$2}' blah.txt
```

Edit2: And a slightly more concise, thanks to Bernhard:

```
$ awk -F+ '{print $1,sum;sum+=$2}' OFS="+" blah.txt
```

Edit3: but the former doesn't display 0 on the first line, so here is a corrected and somewhat packed version that shows the shorter way to answer Tom's question (until some new comment suggests a better one) :

```
$ awk -F+ '{print$1,s+0;s+=$2}' OFS=+ blah.txt
```

Comment: Great thing, I guess that knowledge of toolkit is no less important than knowing regular expressions. +1

Comment: that is sweet !

Comment: Or, put the addition at end. `nawk -F+ '{printf("%s+%d\n",$1,sum);sum+=$2}' blah.txt`

Comment: @Sukminder That would be less portable though, not the (useless) BEGIN clause but the GNU specific options.

Comment: Why not just `print $1,sum` with an output separator specified?

Comment: @Bernhard Why not indeed. Probably because I use C constructions when I have the choice. Your suggestion added to my reply as it is slightly more concise.

Comment: the new solution doesn't print zero in the number column of the first line

Comment: @Tom: add `-v sum=0` as argument or `BEGIN{sum=0}` to code. Uninitialized variables shall have both a numeric value as zero and an empty string. Evaluation is done according to context which they are used. Thus `printf("%s %d", $1, var)` result in `... 0`, as `%d` explicitly tell to interpret as number, and `print $1, var` result in `...""`, (without the quotes of course), as it is interpreted as string.

Comment: @Sukminder answer edited again with a simpler way to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do that is to learn and use regular expressions, cause in the future it will save you a lot of trouble doing that kind of thing.

```
cat blah.txt | gawk 'match($0, /([^0-9]*)([0-9]+)/, ary) {print ary[1] ary[2]-2}'
```

You'll have to substitute last 2 by your shift variable. You should note the usage of `gawk`. As far as I know, regular `awk` can't extract groups from regular expressions.

What this does do? It does a match on `$0`, putting results in `ary`, using regular expression `/([^0-9]*)([0-9]+)/`, which matches: `([^0-9]*)` - 0 or more characters which aren't numbers and puts it at first array index (parentheses are responsible for that thing called grouping), then `([0-9]+)` matches nonzero length number (and puts it as second element of array).

Of course this can be made more elaborate, along with some error checking, special cases of matching etc. - but I encourage you to explore this (namely regular expressions) on your own.

Comment: i am familiar w regular expressions so will try to get to grips with your solution: thanks for taking the time to set out your solution.

Comment: This way I could refresh and extend my miserable awk knowledge, so I can't say it wasn't worth it ;)